# Django MEDIA_URL not working in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've read various answers on how to do this, but still can't seem to get it working.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'c:/jaskaran/dropbox/edmhunters/hunt/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
)
```

I have a 'media/img/' folder in my Django app and a 'static'folder as well.

**view.py**

```
def top100(request):
    top_100_list = DJ.objects.exclude(rank__isnull=True).order_by('rank')
    context = {'top_100_list': top_100_list}
    return render_to_response('hunt/top100.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is how i'm accessing the image in the Django template `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}">`

The image url doesn't add the MEDIA_URL to the image link.

What's missing in this code?

Comment: We had issue while loading image using media. However we just changed from **django.core.context_processors.media** to **django.template.context_processors.media** it solved my purpose and able to load image. **django.template.context_processors.media** is available in Django 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, noob mistake. I was using the `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}">` in the wrong HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to render_to_response looks like the issue, here.

```
return render_to_response('hunt/top100.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))
```

should instead be:

```
return render_to_response('hunt/top100.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing it the django way in the template by appending url to the model field name i.e.

```
<img src="{{ dj.img.url }}">
```

Also works and even more cleaner code compared to:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}">
```